# How do Ioad an Image from a file and draw it on a WPF Skiasharp canvas?

Tags: wpf, skiasharp

SkiaSharp WPF <- Important

[image]

I want to display the Compass.png image at a certain location on my SkiaSharp canvas.  I am already drawing lines and circles on the canvas, I do NOT need help with that.

```
private void MyCanvas_PaintSurface(object sender, SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs e)
{
  var surface = e.Surface;
  var canvas = surface.Canvas;
    
  canvas.Clear(SKColors.Black);
    
  // ... working drawing code drawing lines/circles already here
    
  // ** Need to add code here to load the compass image from the file and display it on the canvas at say (0, 0)?
}
```

Note:  WPF.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Worked it out...

```
var image = SKImage.FromEncodedData(@"Images\Compass.png");
var bm = SKBitmap.FromImage(image);

canvas.DrawBitmap(bm, new SKPoint(0, 0));
```

Obviously, better to just set the bm one time and reuse it.

Comment: Don't forget to Dispose unused resources. SkiaSharp has a lot of objects that are Disposable, you can create serious leaks in your app